# SATA Backplane Interoperability

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, sata

A few weeks ago I bought a used Intel server off of eBay for about $100.  It was ten years old, came with everything except the hard drives, and seemed to be in good condition.  My intention was to use it as a home server.  It worked about as well as one would expect a $100 server to work so I will be replacing the motherboard, probably with [the Asus Z9PA-D8 (8xDDR3, dual Intel LGA2011 CPU sockets)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BRF7DAC) and adding CPUs and RAM compatible with it.

There is however the small problem of the SATA backplane (at least I think its that and not a SAS one).  There are six SATA cables which connect the backplane to the RAID card. It allows the hard drives to be hot swapped.  I have no plans to use the RAID card, but like the backplane.  It makes inserting hard drives very convenient and also has an attached cooling fan.  Is it possible to simply attach the backplane to the new motherboard?  Or will there be issues with interoperability (either due to outdated power connections or special drivers needed)?  I am not familiar with SATA backplanes although they seem simple enough.

Comment: Which model is the $100 server? (And thus also: which backplane did it ship with).  Also you might want to check this befire using the old server chassis for the new board: PSU (old one might have a non-generic layout), size (not all fits in 1U or 2U servers), mounting hole positions and **AIRFLOW**.

Comment: The last bolded because many servers ten d to ship in 1U or 2U cases and are very sensitive to airflow.

Comment: The motherboard you linked to is an Asus, not an Acer. (To the best of my knowledge, Acer doesn't make separate motherboards.) I edited the text of your question so that, should the link become invalid, we'll still have some idea what make and model motherboard this question is talking about.

Comment: The server is a refurbished ten year old Intel tower server (convertible to a 6U rack server I believe).  The seller did not state the age, but the motherboard it came with is an Intel SE7520BD2 which led me to estimate the age at about ten years.  Space is not a concern.  The old board is larger (12" by 13") and the pins underneath it can be adjusted to meet a different size.  The PSU may or may not be ATX, but it's about 9" by 6" and still functions.  The only thing I have little experience with is the backplane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the backplane has a separate additional ribbon cable connection to the Intel motherboard, for out of band signalling and LEDs, there should be no issues in interoperability with the new motherboard. SATA is hotpluggable by design.

Comment: That's what I thought.  I think there may be a second small wire, possibly to do what you say.  However I don't think that will be a huge issue.

Comment: Given that it's a server board and backplane, it's more likely to be SAS than SATA, but that doesn't change the validity of this answer. If anything, SAS should handle being hotplugged *better* than SATA, because on servers with large amounts of storage, hot plugging and unplugging storage devices is almost a daily thing.